# CloudFormation - CodeDeploy deployment group already exists

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CF to create a deployment group for a CodeDeploy application, but I keep getting error that says the deployment group already exists (it does but it belongs to a different CodeDeploy application). If I manually create it, it is fine. Here is the template:

```
"DeploymentGroup": {
  "Description": "Create a deployment group",
  "DependsOn": [
    "EC2Instance"
  ],
  "Type" : "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "ApplicationName" : "Foo",
    "DeploymentConfigName": "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce",
    "DeploymentGroupName": "foo-group",
    "Ec2TagFilters" : [
      {
        "Key" : "Name",
        "Value" : "Foo",
        "Type" : "KEY_AND_VALUE"
      }
    ],
    "ServiceRoleArn" : "...."
  }
},
```

Comment: The name of the deployment group must be unique for each application associated with the deployment group. Just confirming that your configuration as described in your question meets that requirement.

Comment: yes unique within an application, but not unique across all applications. What is troubling is that if I manually create it, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Deployment group name need to be unique with the applicable IAM user or AWS account
- Related doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeploymentGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

The deployment group name needs to be unique if its created as part of a CF stack since its a Name Type:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html

I got around this by prepending the application name to the deployment group name.

```
DeploymentGroup:
  Type: "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup"
  Properties:
    ApplicationName: !Ref DeployApplication
    DeploymentGroupName: !Sub "${DeployApplication}_${DeploymentGroupName}"
    ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt CodeDeployServiceRole.Arn
```